# Why is the matrix norm defined as the "smallest" bound?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am studying the text:
Introduction to Linear Algebra - Models Methods and Theory by Alan Tucker
Link: https://commons.library.stonybrook.edu/ams-books/1/

On page 127/128 of the text (140/141 of the pdf), the norm of a matrix is defined:
[image]
[image]

I understand idea of the norm acting as a bound but I don't understand how it's the "(smallest)" bound.

I would think it would be the largest? Am I missing something ovbious?

Comment: If some bound $B$ works then any larger bound $B$ also works. The smallest bound is the tightest bound and that's the one we want.

Comment: The largest _value_ (of that norm ratio) is the smallest upper bound on that value. Indeed, for any set $S$ we have $\max S=\min\{b\mid\forall s\in S,\;b\geq s\}$ (assuming the maximum exists).

Comment: The smallest bound is equal $\max\left \{{\|Ax\|\over \|x\|}\,:\, x\neq 0\right \}$ so there is some maximum involved.